# Font awesome icons loading on homepage but not inner pages

Tags: wordpress

So recently I migrated my site to new domain and did 301 redirects from normaldomain.co.uk to www.normaldomain.co.uk

After these changes, fontawesome icons stopped working on all inner pages, but they still work on home page.

[image]

Here is the [link](https://www.jmtwoodbuild.co.uk/) to the website.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: When I checked your website, your icons are working fine. I could not see the issue.

Comment: Might be a cache issue as I can see working icons on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

open your web console / web inspector (F12 for Windows) and go to the "network" tab. Refresh the page to see if there are some errors when loading the home page. Try the same on other pages where the fontawesome fails. 
The problem may be a bad linked URL.[image: Console example]

On this example you can see an error when loading the folder /alpimacar

With this information you may still have to solve the problem but may know where's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's happened for cache or bad links.
You may try hard refresh by pressing Shift+R